# Convert dataframe to dictionary but not to take column name as keys in python

Tags: python, dictionary, dataframe

I have a daframe given below. I want to convert it into dictionary. But I Don't want column name as keys.

```
data = {'0':[0.039169993,0.023344912], '1':[0.17865846,0.01093025],'2':[0.039170124,0.023344917], '3':[0.17865846,0.01093025],'4':[0.039170124,0.023344917]}
df= pd.DataFrame(data)



         0.0            1.0          2.0        3.0          4.0
0  0.039169993   0.17865846  0.039170124   0.17865846  0.039170124
1  0.023344912   0.01093025  0.023344917   0.01093025  0.023344917

**Desired Result**:
    {{0: 0.039169993, 1:0.023344912},
     {0: 0.17865846, 1:0.01093025},
     {0: 0.039170124, 1:0.023344917},
     {0: 0.17865846, 1:0.01093025},
     {0:0.039170124, 1:0.023344917}}
```

MyAttempt:

```
df.to_dict()
{'0': {0: 0.039169993, 1: 0.023344912},
 '1': {0: 0.17865846, 1: 0.01093025},
 '2': {0: 0.039170124, 1: 0.023344917},
 '3': {0: 0.17865846, 1: 0.01093025},
 '4': {0: 0.039170124, 1: 0.023344917}}
```

I dont want column name as keys. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `transpose` or `T` and `.to_dict(orient='records')` to obtain the desired output like:

```
df.T.to_dict(orient='records')
```

Answer (score 0):

The desired result has the *format* of a set of dictionaries, but you cannot have a set of dictionaries because dictionaries are not hashable, however you could have a list.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'0': [0.039169993, 0.023344912], '1': [0.17865846, 0.01093025], '2': [0.039170124, 0.023344917],
        '3': [0.17865846, 0.01093025], '4': [0.039170124, 0.023344917]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

result = list(df.to_dict().values())

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[{0: 0.039170124, 1: 0.023344917}, {0: 0.039169993, 1: 0.023344912}, {0: 0.17865846, 1: 0.01093025}, {0: 0.17865846, 1: 0.01093025}, {0: 0.039170124, 1: 0.023344917}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
df.T.to_dict(orient='records')

[{0: 0.039169993, 1: 0.023344911999999999},
 {0: 0.17865845999999999, 1: 0.010930250000000001},
 {0: 0.039170124000000001, 1: 0.023344917},
 {0: 0.17865845999999999, 1: 0.010930250000000001},
 {0: 0.039170124000000001, 1: 0.023344917}]
```